# Reformatting date in string in CGI script

Tags: python, date, cgi, var

i'm running a raspberry pi and my script stores a date in a .txt file, in ISO format like: 2016-12-31

But i wish to transfor this date (comming from a HTML form) and store it like this: 31-12-2016 (%d-%n-%Y)

How can i do this, i can't get the strftime function to work, sorry for nubism.

Comment: You need to show the part of your CGI script that deals with the incoming date. Probably you need to parse the incoming date with `strptime()` into a `datetime` object, then format it with `datetime.strftime()` and write it to your file.

Comment: Ok the script is a bit messy, but with this line i catch the var from the HTML form: 
datevar1 = form.getfirst("datestop").upper()

And with this line i write it to file:

fileoutputvar = lightonvar + '\n' + datevar + '\n'

Comment: To be honest, i lack the skills of this programming language to use "objects".
Could you help me and asume this var is named "datevar", after retreiving it from the form?

Comment: Lemon, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], including a clear description of the problem, and what you've tried to solve it.  "I can't get the `strftime` function to work" doesn't explain much, especially when you haven't _shown_ us what you were doing with it.

Comment: Regarding the code in your comment:  Your question is about string _processing_...  It's not about _fetching_ strings, so showing us how you got your hands on it has nothing to do with the problem --- we already know you have a string.  Likewise, your question is not about saving strings to files, so what you do with the string _after_ processing it is also not helpful, except in a broad "here's my overall goal" sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `datevar1` is assigned the string `'2016-12-31'` from your form you can use the `datetime` module to parse and reformat the date:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime(datevar1, '%Y-%m-%d')
datevar = dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Or in one line:

```
datevar = datetime.strptime(datevar1, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Awesome!! It worked! And helped me find another bug! Thx a lot m8

Comment: @Lemon: no worries. Now that the problem is resolved you might like to consider marking this answer as accepted :)